# Can an IIS App Pool Identity user be granted permissions to a share on another machine?

Tags: iis, permissions, windows-server, network-share

Let's say I have two Windows servers, A and B.

A hosts an asp.net web app called "MySite" with a corresponding application pool. B has a share called "MyShare".

Is it possible to grant permissions to the share for the application pool identity?

I know that if the directory was on server A, I can refer to the identity user account as "IIS AppPool\MySite", but this doesn't work on B.

In addition, granting permissions to a "machine account" (e.g. domain\A$) doesn't seem to have worked. (As described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities)

Comment: Does this meet your needs? for the IIS website on Server A, have the AppPool run under a domain account and for the UNC share on Server B, allow full permissions for the domain account.

Comment: As long as your web apps need to access resources beyond the boundary of the hosting machine, you shouldn't use IIS AppPoolIdentities any more, but a proper service account (usually a domain account). There isn't much to discuss further on why and how.